# Let $T \colon \mathbb R^5 \rightarrow \mathbb R^5 $ be a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra

I came across the following problem that says:

> Let $T \colon \mathbb R^5 \rightarrow \mathbb R^5 $ be a linear transformation.Then which of the following statements is true?
>
> $T$ has
> $1$.No real eigenvalues
> $2$.at least one real eigenvalue
> $3$.at most one real eigenvalue
> $4$.exactly one real eigenvalue.

I do not know how to progress with the problem.Can someone point me in the right direction?Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: What is the degree of the characteristic polynomial? What do you know about real polynomials with odd degree?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try finding some simple counterexamples for 1, 3 and 4 (Hint: take a diagonal matrix). To see that 2 is true, have a look at the degree of the characteristic polynomial of $T$.